# Adding custom browser in Katalon Studio

Tags: automated-tests, opera, web-testing, katalon-studio

I just want to know if in Katalon Studio is possible to add custom browser for an execution ? for example: Opera.

I've seen many things in internet and have tried to add custom browser via project settings. Project Settings-->Desired Capabilities-->Custom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Opera driver with Selenium. So instead of using `WebUI.openBrowser('wwww.example.com')`, use the following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "D:/path-to-operadriver/operadriver_win64/operadriver.exe")
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver()
driver.get('www.example.com')
```

Note: download the Opera driver from [here](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can choose from a number of browsers:

[image]

Katalon will remember the last one used for the next time you click the "Run" button.

Also, you can change the default browser in `Project Settings > Execution > Default execution`.

Comment: No, I mean if I can add Opera browser as an execution browser?

Comment: You will probably need to use a webdriver.

Comment: Okey, I'll try that then.